# Open page two inside the body of page one using Cupertino Segmented Control

Tags: android, flutter, design-patterns

I am using Cupertino Segmente  Control , I created a tab using three swings and assigned three widgets to the front page body. When selecting any of the tabs, it displays the body of the new widget. So far, everything works fine. Products are loaded inside each page, and when we select a product, it must go to the second page .The second page opens, but inside the body of the first page. If you help me, thank you very much

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  int groohEntkhabi = 1;

  final Map<int, Widget> logoBala = const <int, Widget>{
    0: Text("کشاورزی" ,style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),),
    1: Text("خرید فروش" ,style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),),
    2: Text("رهن و اجاره" ,style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),),
  };

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
     
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.blue),
          //centerTitle: true,
          title: Container(

              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(

                    child: CupertinoSegmentedControl(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                      groupValue: groohEntkhabi,
                      onValueChanged: (changeFromGroupValue) {
                        setState(() {
                          groohEntkhabi = changeFromGroupValue;
                        });
                      },
                      children: logoBala,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              )


          ),

          actions: [

            IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.search), onPressed: (){}),
          ],
        ),
        drawer: MyDraver(),
        bottomNavigationBar: MyBottomNavigation(),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
          onPressed: () {}, label: Text("ثبت رایگان آگهی",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),), icon:Icon(Icons.add,color: Colors.white,),backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        ),
        // floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: (){
        //   // Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
        //   //     builder: (context) => Shoab()
        //   // ));
        // },
        //   shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
        //   backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrange,
        //   child:Center(child: Text("ثبت رایگان آگهی")),),
        floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,


        body:
        (
            _childern(groohEntkhabi)
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  Widget _childern(index){
    List<Widget> page_screen=[];
    page_screen.add(_keshavarzi());
    page_screen.add(kharidFroosh());
    page_screen.add(_ejare());
    return page_screen[index];

  }

  Widget kharidFroosh(){

    return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        localizationsDelegates: [
          // ... app-specific localization delegate[s] here
          GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
          GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
          GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
        ],
        supportedLocales: [
          const Locale('en', ''), // farsi
        ],

        home: ListView.builder(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 3.0,left: 3.0,right: 3.0),

          itemBuilder: mycard_view1,itemCount: 5,));
  }
  Widget mycard_view1(BuildContext context ,int index){
    String mogheiatt ="کوی ملا نفس";
    String mogheiat = mogheiatt.length>14 ? mogheiatt.substring(0,14):mogheiatt;
    return Card(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),),
      elevation: 1.0,

      //color: Colors.blue,

      child: InkWell(

        onTap: (){

          Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (BuildContext context) => Safhe2_kharid_froosh()));
        },
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget> [


            Container(margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(50.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.5),
              height: 160.0,
              width: double.infinity,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white,borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
              child: Padding(
                padding:  EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(100.0,10.0,10.0,2.0),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                  children: <Widget>[

                    Text("فروش ویلایی",style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "shabnammedium",fontSize: 15.0),),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 7.0,
                    ),
                    Text("قیمت : 850 م تومان",style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "shabnammedium",fontSize: 15.0),),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 7.0,
                    ),
                    Text("متراژ : 85 متر ",style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "shabnammedium",fontSize: 15.0),),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 30.0,
                    ),
                    Row(
                      //crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Container(

                          decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Color(0xffe1f5fe),borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),),
                          child: Center(child: Padding(
                            padding:  EdgeInsets.only(left: 3.0,right: 3.0),
                            child: Row(
                              children: [
                                Text("روز پیش",style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "shabnamlight",color: Colors.black87),),
                                Text("5",style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "shabnamlight",color: Colors.black87),),

                              ],
                            ),
                          )),
                          // width: 70.0,
                        ),
                        Container(

                          child: Row(
                            children: [
                              Text("...",style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "shabnamlight",color: Colors.black87),),
                              Text(mogheiat,style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "shabnamlight",color: Colors.black87),
                                maxLines: 1,
                                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                              ),

                            ],
                          ),
                          //width: 100.0,

                        ),


                      ],
                    ),




                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),

            Positioned(
              left: 10.0,
              top: 5.0,
              bottom: 5.0,
              child: ClipRRect(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),

                child:Image.asset("images/home.jpg",width: 130,fit: BoxFit.cover,),
              ),
            ),

          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  Widget _keshavarzi(){
    return Keshavarzi();
  }
  Widget _ejare(){
    return Ejare();
  }
}
```

this is my images app

[this is my secend page inside a first page body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9Dgm.jpg)

[and this my first pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CvPVy.jpg)

Comment: Can you also add some code. And is it currently opening the next page inside the body or is that what you want it to do but it currently doesnt?

Comment: It now opens inside the body